# How do I activate an option in a dropdown menu without a button in Blender Python

Tags: python, scripting

I want to select an option in a dropdown menu and have it activated instantly. The code I have makes me push a button to confirm the option.

I don't want the Add object button, I want to add a sphere as soon as I select the Add sphere option.

This is what I have right now

[image]

This is my code:

```
import bpy


class MyProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    
    my_enum : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name= "Enumerator / Dropdown",
        description= "sample text",
        items= [('OP1', "Add Cube", ""),
                ('OP2', "Add Sphere", ""),
                ('OP3', "Add Suzanne", "")
        ]
    )


class ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Main Panel"
    bl_idname = "ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "New Tab"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
        
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_enum")

        layout.operator("addonname.myop_operator")


class ADDONNAME_OT_my_op(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add Object"
    bl_idname = "addonname.myop_operator"
    
    
    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
        
        if mytool.my_enum == 'OP1':
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()


            
            
        if mytool.my_enum == 'OP2':
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add()

            
        
        
        
        if mytool.my_enum == 'OP3':
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add()

            
        
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
    


classes = [MyProperties, ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel, ADDONNAME_OT_my_op]
 
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        
        bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type= MyProperties)
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `bpy.props.EnumProperty`'s [update](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty) method to add custom behaviour when its state changes.

Add this line to the enum annotation :

`update=lambda self, context: bpy.ops.addonname.myop_operator()`

You should note however that using an operator  in an `update` method is not supposed to be supported, so it may or may not adversely affect your file afterwards or cause random crashes. I can't find the source but I read it from a developer note not long ago.

The "Blender" way to do it is to select the item, then click on the button, like you're doing right now.

Comment: It works. Thank you.